# jQuery UI Autocomplete, How to enable autocomplete only if user type in a special charactor?

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have Autocomplete attached to different types of input box. It loads items whenever user start type in anything which is fine. But,in **one of the textarea**, I want to disable autocomplete by default, and enable it if user type in "@". How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$('textarea').autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
})
    .autocomplete('disable')
    .on('keypress', function(event) {
        //Detect whether '@' was keyed.
        if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode === 64) {
            $(this).autocomplete('enable');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Live Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/rRu4A/3

Comment: I typed in @A in the Live Example, it doesn't start loading

Comment: That's because "@" isn't in any of the options.  I altered my example so that the "@" never actually appears in the `textarea`, it just turns on the functionality.  Try it again.

Comment: @Jenny Type "@a".  "@" will activate the autocomplete and "a" will show you some options.

Comment: I typed in "@a" , it doesn't trigger anything.

Comment: I just tried IE, it works. But Firefox does't. Firefox still shows "@" and no response. But I need to show "@", just like this site, when there's "@", user will receive message of notice. Can we use another way to do this?

Comment: How about something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/rRu4A/4/?  You might also want to look into this plugin - http://imankulov.github.com/asuggest/.

Comment: Perfectly working! Thanks for your helping! I will study the plugin you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer worked well enough if you started off your input with '@' but not so well when the '@' was embedded deeper down in the middle of a paragraph.  I am still working on a better solution, but this is what I have so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        function getCurrentWord(el) {
            var $t = $(el),
                v = $t.val(),
                minLength = $t.data('uiAutocomplete').options.minLength,
                start = $t.prop('selectionStart'),
                end = $t.prop('selectionEnd'),
                re = /(\@[^\s]+)/g,
                matches = [], m;
                
            if (start !== end) // user has text highlighted
                return false;
            
            while((m = re.exec(v)) != null) {
                var endIndex = m.index + m[1].length;
                if (start >= m.index && start <= endIndex) {
                    var result = { 
                        start: m.index,
                        end: endIndex,
                        value: m[1]
                    };
                    return result.value.length >= minLength && result;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        
        $('textarea').autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
        focus: function() {
          //  Don't let navigating the menu overwrite textarea value
          return false;
        },
            search: function(event, ui) {
                var word = getCurrentWord(this);
                if (word) return word.value;
                return false;
            },
        select: function(event, ui) {
          var fullValue = ui.item.value;
          var target = getCurrentWord(this);
          var value = $(this).val();
          if (target)
            $(this).val(
                value.slice(0, target.start) 
                + fullValue 
                + value.slice(target.end)
              );

                  return false;
        },
        source: function(req, response) {
          var word = getCurrentWord(this.element);
          response([
            'Adam',
            'Alice',
            'Bjorn',
            'Cathryn',
            'Chris',
            'David',
            'Edward',
            'Francis',
            'George',
            'Hermen',
            'Heidi',
            'Issac',
            'Jennifer',
            'Katie',
            'Kristen',
            'Larry',
            'Melinda',
            'Nina',
            'Oliver',
            'Peter',
            'Quagmire',
            'Rodger',
            'Stacey',
            'Trevor',
            'Ulysses',
            'Victor',
            'William'
            ].map(function(s) { return '@' + s; })
             .filter(function(s) {
                if (!word) return true;
                else return s.toLowerCase().startsWith(word.value.toLowerCase());
             }));
        }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
```